# Can an external light fixture and an external receptacle share a circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have to get power to provide an outlet for an awning at high level.

The nearest power source is an external light fixture. Can I wire into this? If so is there anything special I should know?

Comment: Are you planning for the outlet to be switched with the light, or are you planning to do some rewiring?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the NEC does not prohibit putting an outside light fixture and an outside receptacle on the same circuit.

Comment: +1 Particularly in the OP's case for exterior fixtures. While we did the electrical *in the house* to keep lights and outlets separate I kept them together for the outdoor GFCI circuit so that I would know if the breaker tripped.

Answer (score 4):

Should you? No, Greebo is right (+1), lights and outlets should be separate.

Can you? Maybe, it depends on whether the power source is at the light fixture, or at the light switch. If it's at the light switch, then your outlet would also be switched.

What do you need to know? Everything about electrical safety and codes so that you don't electrocute yourself or create a dangerous situation. Things like turning the power off at the breaker, testing the lines before you touch anything, using a GFCI outlet, using an outlet cover for exterior protection, stapling the wire to the stud, using the proper gauge wire, etc. If any of that list leaves you scratching your head, it would be best to hire a professional.

Comment: Let me give a strong second to your advice to hit the books hard or bring in a professional. Electrical work isn't something you can do half-heartedly without risking serious repercussions. If you do go the book route, Mullin's *Electrical Wiring: Residential* is a good place to start, but you'll need to go elsewhere for workaday practical electrical safety; it's only concerned with teaching how to wire to Code.

Answer (score 1):

Lights and outlets should never be wired on the same circuit, because if you blow the breaker for the outlet, you're left in the dark.

Comment: That may be good advice in many cases, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: There are exceptions to every rule.  It can be useful to use a GFCI receptacle to protect an outdoor light circuit.

Comment: Counterpoint: If you wire light + receps to one breaker, but put each room on a different circuit, then you know when you tripped the breaker because your lights go out in one room, but the light on in the next room makes it no safety issue. Bathrooms and kitchens are the only places where Code requires lighting and receps to be on separate circuits by forcing you to dedicate circuits to just the receps.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman ..and even then, you can still combine the bathroom lights with half the receptacles in the dining room and the light in the crawlspace, if you really wanted to. But if you do this, beware: someone might mistake you for a licensed electrician.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman Code does not require lighting and receptacles to be on different circuits in the kitchen, it simply requires dedicated small appliance circuits.  You could have other receptacles in the kitchen that are on the light circuit (not saying it's a good idea, just saying it is possible).

Comment: I didn't say it was a code requirement.  One can and, IMO, should strive to do better than code.  Though I do like the 1 room per circuit model too - though it assumes that lights in other rooms are being left on - not very green... ;)

Comment: With everyone carrying cellphones AKA expensive talking flashlights, I feel like there is less risk of being eaten by a grue due to power loss than ever before.